# Problem with external monitor: Ubuntu 23.10, msi computer, nvidia graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 23.10

I have an msi computer with nvidia GTX 880M graphics card (in addition to an integrated intel card). I am using as screen a large samsung tv (my eyesight needs it ...). This was working without much problems, with the latest ubuntu 23.20. But because of some hardware problems I had to do a complete reinstall of 23.10

After the reinstall, everything works ... except the external monitor! The pc does not even recognize it, the settings --- Displays do not show any of the usual about configuring dual screen.

Searching --- it seems I need to use the nvidia driver, trying to install using help from https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/  specifically the 470 driver, using

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

But it does not work,  even

```
nvidia-smi     
No devices were found
```

Any ideas? What can I do? If there is some extra info I should give, please tell me.

**Edit**

I am not sure what extra info is needed, but here is some which might be relevant:

```
sudo lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1421312  0
nvidia_drm             77824  0
nvidia_modeset       1212416  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35590144  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        270336  3 drm_display_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   761856  19 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,nvidia,drm_buddy,nvidia_drm,i915,ttm
video                  73728  3 msi_wmi,i915,nvidia_modeset
```

but

```
ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/  | grep nvidia
```

returns blank!  and

```
nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

**Edit 2**

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink 
Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 2 associated providers: 
0 name:modesetting

xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
0: +*eDP-1 1920/382x1080/215+0+0  eDP-1
```

**Edit 3**

Some additional info after first answer: (will be adding)

```
sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for kjetil: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104M [GeForce GTX 880M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:36 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Edit 4**

I have been to a technician who thinks it is a hardware problem, the HDMI port is somehow damaged. But there is also an  mini-displayport, so I bought an converter mini-displayport-HDMI. With this there is some communication with the external Samsung screen ( I can use the screen to wiev videos on my harddisk!), but still it doesnt find it computer monitor use. The following output might be useful:

```
xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x44) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  96625
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.63:1.0:1.5
    Brightness: 0.77
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000daf201700000000
        02150103802615780ad895a3554d9d27
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101012e3680a070381f403020
        35007ed710000018000000fe004e3137
        334847452d4c31310a20000000fe0043
        4d4f0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004e3137334847452d4c31310a20006e
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 79 
        supported: 79
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x44) 138.700MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1920x1080 (0x45) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1680x1050 (0x46) 119.272MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.82KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  60.02Hz
  1400x1050 (0x47) 122.091MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.94KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  60.02Hz
  1600x900 (0x48) 97.818MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.58KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x49) 108.001MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1400x900 (0x4a) 86.703MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.58KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0x4b) 108.036MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x810 (0x4c) 151.990MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.99KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  60.02Hz
  1368x768 (0x4d) 72.451MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.42KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x4e) 71.131MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.40KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x720 (0x4f) 64.044MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.48KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x50) 65.017MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.38KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.02Hz
  960x720 (0x51) 117.039MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.03KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.02Hz
  928x696 (0x52) 109.095MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.31KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.02Hz
  896x672 (0x53) 102.410MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.67KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x576 (0x54) 42.141MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.59KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  60.02Hz
  960x600 (0x55) 77.027MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.06KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.02Hz
  960x540 (0x56) 37.375MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.37KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  60.02Hz
  800x600 (0x57) 38.413MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.51KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  60.02Hz
  840x525 (0x58) 59.636MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.82KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  60.02Hz
  864x486 (0x59) 30.730MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  30.01KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  60.02Hz
  700x525 (0x5a) 61.045MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.94KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  60.02Hz
  800x450 (0x5b) 48.909MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.58KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  60.02Hz
  640x512 (0x5c) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  700x450 (0x5d) 43.351MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.58KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  60.02Hz
  640x480 (0x5e) 25.208MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.51KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.02Hz
  720x405 (0x5f) 22.130MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  25.15KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  60.02Hz
  684x384 (0x60) 36.225MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.41KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  60.02Hz
  640x360 (0x61) 17.958MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.45KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  60.02Hz
  512x384 (0x62) 32.508MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.38KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.02Hz
  512x288 (0x63) 21.034MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.53KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  60.02Hz
  480x270 (0x64) 18.687MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.37KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  60.02Hz
  400x300 (0x65) 19.175MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  37.45KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  60.02Hz
  432x243 (0x66) 15.365MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  30.01KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  60.02Hz
  320x240 (0x67) 12.580MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.45KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.02Hz
  360x202 (0x68) 11.038MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  25.09KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  60.02Hz
  320x180 (0x69)  8.979MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.45KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  60.02Hz
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  96625
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 76 
        supported: 76
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
kjetil@kjetil-computer:~$
```

Note at the end `VGA-1 disconnected`  ?

Comment: Can you add the output of "xrandr --listproviders" and "xrandr --listmonitors"

Comment: @yalin:  Done..........................

Comment: Not sure, but could you check [my answer to a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267499/906933). I had to create the config file in order to get my 2nd monitor running

Comment: Hello. Just to clarify what you are looking for. Do you need NVIDIA Drivers? I have a similar machine (older actually) Its doing multi monitor using default wayland drivers.

Comment: @jpbrain: I have drivers installed ... But they do not seem to work. You say ypu have multimonitor with wayland? I have Xorg. O am syarting to think this might be a hardware problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup with the NVIDA 470 drivers and needed to generate a xorg.conf file with the bundled Nvidia Software.
[image: 1]

Press "Save to X Config.." button and put it into the  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` folder.

Reboot and make sure to start the X Session, not the Wayland session. This way I could use all of my monitors...